# Find the total for a bank account

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, subclass, superclass

I'm a student just finished my first year learning java and had the question "create a method that returns the total money in the Bank?" in an exam. I've included the classes below. I got most of the methods correct including addAccount(), getBalance(), withdraw(), etc. but was not sure what the answer to this one was. This is probably simple and more simpler than I think it is (that I have to use a for loop or two of some kind) but just to clarify the correct way of adding up totals. This also came up in a c# assignment for a grocery store where the customer bought goods from different products i.e fruit vegetable etc. and a grand total had to be calculated.

Thank you in advance...

Paul

Code:
Superclass:

```
    /**
   A bank account has a balance that can be changed by 
   deposits and withdrawals.
*/
public class BankAccount
{ 
   //Declare balance field
   private double balance; 

   /**
      Constructs a bank account with a zero balance.
   */
   public BankAccount()
   {  
      balance = 0;
   }

   /**
      Constructs a bank account with a given balance.
      @param initialBalance the initial balance
   */
   public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
   {  
      balance = initialBalance;
   }

   /**
      Deposits money into the bank account.
      @param amount the amount to deposit
   */
   public void deposit(double amount) 
   {  
      balance = balance + amount;
   }

   /**
      Withdraws money from the bank account.
      @param amount the amount to withdraw
   */
   public void withdraw(double amount) 
   {  
        if (balance >= amount)
        {
        balance = balance - amount;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Withdrawal error: insufficent funds");
        }
   }

   /**
      Gets the current balance of the bank account.
      @return the current balance
   */
   public double getBalance()
   {  
      return balance; 
   }

   /**
      Transfers money from the bank account to another account
      @param amount the amount to transfer
      @param other the other account
   */
   public void transfer(double amount, BankAccount other)
   {  
      withdraw(amount);
      other.deposit(amount);
   }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Your Balance: "+ balance; 
    }
}
```

Subclass checking account:

```
    /**
   A checking account that charges transaction fees.
*/
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount
{
   private int transactionCount;
   private int transaction;

   private static final int FREE_TRANSACTIONS = 0;
   private static final double TRANSACTION_FEE = 2.0;

   /**
      Constructs a checking account with a given balance.
      @param initialBalance the initial balance
   */
   public CheckingAccount(double initialBalance)
   {  
      // Construct superclass
      super(initialBalance);

      // Initialize transaction count
      transactionCount = 0; 
   }

   public void deposit(double amount) 
   {  
      transactionCount++;
      // Now add amount to balance 
      super.deposit(amount); 
   }

   public void withdraw(double amount) 
   {  
      transactionCount++;
      // Now subtract amount from balance 
      super.withdraw(amount); 
   }

   /**
      Deducts the accumulated fees and resets the
      transaction count.
   */
   public void deductFees()
   {  
      if (transactionCount > FREE_TRANSACTIONS)
      {  
         double fees = TRANSACTION_FEE *
               (transactionCount - FREE_TRANSACTIONS);
         super.withdraw(fees);
      }
      transaction = transactionCount;
   }

    public String toString()
    {

        return super.toString() + "\t Your Transactions: "+ transaction; 
    }

}
```

subclass savings account:

```
    /**
   An account that earns interest at a fixed rate.
*/
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
{  
   private double interestRate;

   /**
      Constructs a bank account with a given interest rate.
      @param rate the interest rate
   */
   public SavingsAccount(double rate) 
   { 
        interestRate = rate;
   }

   /**
      Constructs a bank account with a given interest rate.
      @param rate the interest rate
   */
   public SavingsAccount(double rate, double initBalance) 
   {  
      super(initBalance);
      interestRate = rate;
   }

   /**
      Adds the earned interest to the account balance.
   */
   public void addInterest() 
   {  
      double interest = getBalance() * interestRate + 100;
      deposit(interest); 
   }

        public String toString()
    {

        return super.toString() + "\t Your Interest rate: "+ interestRate; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.

If you have a collection of BankAccounts or subclasses of it, you can simple sum them in a for loop.

Lets say you have something like this (I assume that there is a Bank object containing a function that gives me all accounts in some way):

```
Collection<BankAccount> accounts = Bank.getAccounts();
Double sum = 0.0;
for (BankAccount account : accounts) {
    sum += account.getBalance();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that guys and for giving me some sample code to mess with, i'm glad to know I was on the right track but it's good to have a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track thinking about a loop. Just sum the balances.

```
public static double totalBalance(Collection<BankAccount> accounts){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(BankAccount b : accounts){
        sum += b.getBalance();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I would expect the getBalance() method to always result in the correct balnce for the account and the addInterest() and dectutFees() methods to be called frequently by a Bankcontroler or so.  If you use them every time you check the balance, they would change the balance and the balance would depend on the number of times you checked it. This seems wrong to me...

Comment: You're probably right. Calling deductFees() often won't hurt, since it doesn't change the balance if there haven't been more transactions. However, I now see that addInterest always adds the same amount of interest, regardless of the "time" that has passed since it was last called. I'll get rid of that part.